# Find the name of the department having the maximum average salary

Tags: mysql

I tried with the following query to get department name but not achieving completely.

```
select Dep_name as dept_name
from salary
group by Dep_name
order by avg_salary desc
limit 1;
```

the table looks like

```
emp_id  Dep_name     salary
34      Marketing    35000
35      Sales        48000
36      Admin        23000
37      Sales        67000
38      Sales        97000
39      Marketing    98000
40      Admin        57000
41      Admin        71000
42      Marketing    80000
```

getting output as 'Sales' i.e. highest Avg_salary among the departments

I guess the output should be 'Marketing'

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Your query should do what you want, assuming it is valid for your database.

Comment: i guess its mysql

Comment: What if departments are tied on average salary?

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select avg(salary),Dep_name from Table1
group by Dep_name
order by avg(salary) desc
limit 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0efe8c/11

Answer (score 0):

I did a few modifications and got it.

```
SELECT Dep_name
FROM salary
GROUP BY Dep_name
ORDER BY AVG(salary) desc
LIMIT 1;
```